# Editing using Kendo UI angular grid external form(using a popup)

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, angular9

I am editing using kendo ui angular grid in using rest api, that opens the edit component in the popup. 
I am referring https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/

When I edit the record, the grid does not gets refreshed, only after if I F5 the page, the updated data is shown.

```
  //Emp-List Component
  private view: Observable<GridDataResult>;
  constructor(private service: EmployeeService) {
  this.view = this.service;
  this.service.getEmpList();
  }

  public saveHandler(employee: Employee) {
  this.service.updateEmployee(employee);
  this.service.getEmpList();
  this.editDataItem = undefined;
  }


  export class EmployeeService extends BehaviorSubject<GridDataResult> {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  super(null);
  }

  readonly APIUrl = 'http://localhost:12121/api/employee';

  private getEmployee(): Observable<GridDataResult> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.APIUrl}`).pipe(
  map(
    (response) =>
      <GridDataResult>{
        data: response,
        total: 100,
      }
    )
  );
  }

  public getEmpList(): void {
  this.getEmployee().subscribe((x) => super.next(x));
  }  

  updateEmployee(employee: Employee) {

  return this.http
  .put(`${this.APIUrl}/${employee.employeeID}`, employee)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Employee updated ', data);
  });
  }
  }
```

Comment: How does your `EmployeeService` look like?
From the snippet you posted it looks correct.

Comment: Modified to add the Employeeservice